# Clarification about expressions in Java

Tags: java, expression

Based on this doc: it says the example cadence = 0 is an expression, which is the bolded part out of int cadence = 0;

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

How is not the whole statement int cadence = 0; an expression? Would not the whole initialization not count as an expression? That was what I thought the case and told in in my classes back then.

Additionally, how is "value1 == value2" an expression in the statement System.out.println("value1 == value2");? Is it because we are evaluating to a new String literal to a String value? Does that mean a literal alone such as 5, 4.5, false is an expression in Java? In that case a String literal alone is being treated as an expression.

Comment: You seem to mix up expression and statement. An expression is anything that evaluates to a value.

Comment: Yes, so in this case if I did int x = 0; would not the whole statement itself be considered an expression?

Comment: No. `int x = 0;` is a statement, but not an expression.

Comment: I see. Why is not the data type (int) not needed in this case for it to be expression? Is it because it is not needed to evaluate to a value?

Answer (score 1):

An *expression* ([JLS §15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html)) is some code that can be evaluated and results in a *value*. Notable expressions are *(incomplete list)*:

- Literals, e.g. `42` and `"Hello World"`
- Variables, e.g. `primeNumber` and `person.name`
- Array access, e.g. `arr[3]`
- Operators, e.g. `6 * 7`, `a <= 12`, `i++`, `i = 3`, and `! done`
- Method calls, e.g. `add(4, 6)` and `person.getName()` (non-void methods only)
- Instance creation, e.g. `new Person()`

A *statement* is a piece of code that can be executed inside a `{ }` block ([JLS §14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2)), e.g.

- `if` and `switch` *(conditionals)*
- `for`, `while`, and `do-while` *(loops)*
- `int i` and `String greeting = "Hello"` *(local variable declaration)*
- `return`, `break`, and `continue`
- `try` and `throw`

Some *expressions* can also be used as *statements*, and are known as *"expression statements"* ([JLS §14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)):

- Assignments, e.g. `i = 3`
- Pre/post increment/decrement, e.g. `++i`, `i++`, `i--`, and `--i`
- Method calls, e.g. `foo.setNum(13)` (incl. void methods)
- Instance creation, e.g. `new Person()`

---

> How is not the whole statement `int cadence = 0;` an expression?

It is a *local variable declaration statement*, with *initializer*. Only the *initializer*, i.e. the part between the `=` sign and the `;`, is an *expression*.

That is different from `cadence = 0`, which is an *assignment operator expression*, and needs to be part of a larger *statement*.

Both are different from `cadence = 0;` *(note the semi-colon)*, which is an *assignment expression statement*.

---

> How is `"value1 == value2"` an expression in the statement `System.out.println("value1 == value2");`? Is it because we are evaluating to a new String literal to a String value? Does that mean a literal alone such as `5`, `4.5`, `false` is an expression in Java? In that case a String literal alone is being treated as an expression.

Correct, literals like `5`, `4.5`, `false`, and `"Hello"` are all *expressions*.